# How to hide/delete/ignore a specfic span type

Tags: html, css

I am generating HTML output for ePub from LaTeX source.
But, am having difficulty eliminating the "Chapter " at the start of each chapter. So, wondering if there is an easy way to tell the HTML reader that this is some form of comment so as to *not* display this in the output?

```
<span class="titlemark">Chapter&#x00A0;1</span>
```

Ideally, I'd like to eliminate the `<br />` that follows this as well, but not sure that that would be easy.

### Notes:

- The command line tool I am using [htlatex](https://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html) which takes a .tex file and produces HTML.

Comment: What program do you use to generate the output? Could you add an automated post-processing step?

Comment: @Anthon: I am using `latexht`, but am a bit of newbie with it.  For now I have used `sed` to remove it, but thought perhaps there was a better way. Eventually will have to figure out how to eliminate in the first place.

Comment: Do you have a link for latexht?

Comment: @Anthon: Have added a link in the text.

Comment: The `latexht` instead of `htlatex` in your previous comment got me of to the wrong tangent. Google search is not smart enough to see through that (and neither am I).

Comment: @Anthon: Oppss. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an html editor which supports wild card or RegEx search and replace like Adobe Dreamweaver you could delete these out of the source code very quickly.  See image below-

[image]

Also you can go to RegEx tester sites like these to form the most effective search expression for your needs. http://regex101.com/

Comment: That is sort of what I resorted to but used a `perl` script to remove it.  Did not know about regex101 so thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to suppress both those tags using CSS in an included  `.css` file  (or inserting in the HTML code between `<style>` and `</style>`):

```
span.titlemark, span.titlemark + br {
    display: none;
}
```

But you would have to test that on all devices to see if their renderers correctly handle it.¹

If you don't want to go into the effort of testing this, it is better to remove both nodes altogether, with appropriate parsing of the input. Using python (2.x) and the [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) package², you can do:

```
import sys
import io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with io.open(sys.argv[1]) as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)

for node in soup.select("span.titlemark"):
    print node.get_text()
    sibling = node.find_next_sibling()
    if sibling and sibling.name == 'br' and not sibling.get_text():
        sibling.extract()
    node.extract()

with io.open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(unicode(soup))
```

to get rid of both.³ BeautifulSoup [supports several html/xml parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), depending on the type and quality of the output of `htlatex`, you might need to experiment with the alternatives to get better/faster results.

`htlatex` is a shell script, so you could make a copy (`/usr/local/bin/htlatexstrip`) and add calling the python script as a postprocessing step in there.

¹ <sub>The X + Y suppresses the sibling `<br />` node</sub>
² <sub>install with `pip install beautifulsoup4` or `easy_install beautifulsoup4`</sub>
³ <sub>I am sure you can do something like that easily in PERL (or Ruby) as well, **I** just don't know how</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to remain in the source code, but simply hide them in the browser output, you might add the following statement to your style sheets :

```
.titlemark {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CSS to style the titlemark class with "visibility: hidden" or "display:none".

Comment: Can you provide the exact CSS code required. I am not that familiar with CSS, especially for a `span class`.

Comment: `visibility: hidden` would leave the space for the tag in the rendering.